# QGIS 'invisible feature'

Tags: qgis, null-geometry

I have a shapefile with 1722 rows representing a road network. There is a feature somewhere, somehow that is kind of invisible, specifically the feature with id 1780. When I execute an expression

```
 "id" = 1780
```

the bar shows there is a result somewhere. When I try to zoom on the selected result it's nowhere. I'm asking because I try to load the dataset into postgis and this way I'm getting a null geometry.

Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: You said it yourself, it's a null geometry.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I find it in the shapefile dataset so I can delete it? When I try to zoom in the selected it zooms nowhere

Comment: Use the attribute table. If it's selectable, you can simply delete it

Answer (score 2):

Manually, you can zoom to the layer's extent, open the attribute table, and delete the row with the id you already know.

A python solution is given at [How to select features with NULL Geometry from Shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/how-to-select-features-with-null-geometry-from-shapefiles)