# Simplify Geometries 'NoneType' Error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, error, simplify

I need to simplify the geometries of a large amount of polygons, yet every time I run the Simplify Geometries tool in QGIS, I get the error message below.

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type' See log for more details**

What is causing that error? How can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you have an empty (Null) geometry. You will need to find and delete any empty geometries https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/how-to-select-features-with-null-geometry-from-shapefiles

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select By Expression` function with this expression

```
 $geometry IS NOT NULL
```

then use `Simplify Geometries` tool
that apply the function only on **'Typed'** geometries

Or remove your NULL geom if you want